Is the 1D representation in the following popular youtube video correct?
As per my understanding 1-euclidean dimension generally means a line which means there is no width or thickness, only length. But in this Youtube video about 4-D (from 20s to 65s) 1-D is depicted as that 1-D creatures can move perpendicular to the length (from 38s to 42s in the video). That is strange because such movements signify 2-D not 1-D. What is the meaning of this representation? (I am not sure if this is a comprehension error of mine since it seems a well followed channel over 40 million subscribers and the video itself has over 2 million views yet no one seemed to have commented or noticed if it is an error or an misrepresentation. But I decided to ask here anyway. I apologise in advance for the limited scope of this question)

The narrator said it right: in a 1-D world, a point can only move to the left or right. However the visualization is misleading.

Sometimes bad things are popular.
The depiction in the video is confusing for exactly the reason you say: it shows a 1D line-like universe, then immediately shows objects moving perpendicularly to the line.
I don't see any interpretation that redeems it.
Later, the video claims that a 4-dimensional being would be able to see people's emotions as color-coded auras. This too seems dubious.
